# How to connect to an old version of Oracle (Oracle 9i) from C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am trying to make a connection from C# to an Oracle database which is Oracle 9i when using the class that I normally have to make connections to Oracle marks me the following message

> **ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**

The credentials are fine, if I try to start from the sqldeveloper, I can enter without problems

```
ing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testConexion.CONN
{
public class Ora_Conexion_ADQUIS
{
    private OracleConnection cn { get; set; }

    public OracleConnection getConn()
    {
        if (cn == null)
        {

        string pass = "Password=xxxxxxxxxxx;";
            //string conexion = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CONEXION_ORACLE_ADQUIS"].ToString();
            /*string conexion = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=000.00.000.0)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mtu)));User Id = ADQUIS; Password = admtu160741;";*/
            string conexion = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=000.00.000.0)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MTU)));User Id = xxxxxx;"+pass;
            //string conexion = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=000.00.000.0)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=mtu)));User Id=adquis;Password=admtu160741;";
            //string conexion= "DATA SOURCE = 000.00.000.0:1521 / MTU; PASSWORD = admtu160741; USER ID = ADQUIS";

            cn = new OracleConnection(conexion);

        }
        return cn;
    }
}
}
```

**I have the version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client V. 12.1.2416** and I changed it to the most recent one and nothing, I tried the last one in the nuget but it doesn't let me. Any idea what I need to do? or how to do it another way ?. I cannot update the bd to the most recent version since it is the one of the work and it is the one that is currently working.

I am working with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: try looking [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - my employer(!) just got off of 9i a few years ago. (We're all the way up to 11.2. `LISTAGG`! Wooo!! :-) Lack of support from the vendor is not an issue if the customer just wants to avoid spending any money.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica because it is the one used in the system that is at work and I find myself migrating from platform to a web version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a question of C#, it depends on the driver you use.

ODP.NET Managed Driver requires a database 10.2 or newer as documented in [System Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/InstallSystemRequirements.htm#ODPNT149):

> Access to Oracle Database 10g Release 2 or later

Following the [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1) you need a client/ODP.NET Driver version 11.2 or older.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Data.OracleClient`. Just set your application bitness to be the same as your Oracle Client bitness (32/64 bit, `Any CPU` won't work). Tested with .NET5 & Oracle 9i.

[image]